# How do I align this table inside the white container?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Above is a table which I want to be placed completely inside the white region. So I need it to be shifted to the left side. 
This is the table:

```
    <table class="inventory" style="float:left; position:relative;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
      <th>OT</th>
      <th>Leaves</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM employee');
   $sth->execute();
     $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
    foreach ($data as $row ){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $row['name']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rate" value="<?php echo $row['rate']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="OT" value="<?php echo $row['overtime_hrs']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Leaves" value="<?php echo $row['leaves_per_month']?>"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Total" value="<?php echo $row['total']?>"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.table { 
width: 20%;
border-collapse: collapse; 
border-spacing: 0;
float:left;
}
```

I just added float:left, but that didn't work either.

Comment: share your complete code this is not appropriate to figure out why this is aligned like this..

Comment: And the css, where is?

Comment: Please create snippet or bin which produce the problem. We can't guess..

Comment: Still it is not a complete code, I would like to see the parent elements and CSS of those elements. I believe some element has margin from left. FYI, width and float does not work with `<table>`